# ASP.NET image control does not show the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am using an image control, but it does not display any image. When I see its viewsource, it displays the image path correct. The URL of the page is `devweb.tsgdomain.com/americaneyenew/News.aspx`

```
lblTitle.Text = dtNews.Rows[0]["NewsTitle"].ToString();
string strPhotosImage = dtNews.Rows[0]["Image"].ToString();
if (strPhotosImage != string.Empty)
{
    string Extension = strPhotosImage.Substring(strPhotosImage.LastIndexOf("."));
   // Server.MapPath("~/ENewsLetterFileUpload/NPH_" + strOriginalFileName + "_1.PDF");
    ImgNews.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/ENewsImage/" + iNewsID + "_1" + Extension);
        //Server.MapPath("~/ENewsImage/" + iNewsID + "_1" + Extension);
        //"../ENewsImage/" + iNewsID + "_1" + Extension;
    ImgNews.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    ImgNews.Visible = false;
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

you shouldn't use as server.mappath

```
ImgNews.ImageUrl = "~/ENewsImage/" + iNewsID + "_1" + Extension;
```

would be enough.

Comment: server.mappath will give you path of document on local computer. ex : c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\... but this wont work for you. when you use "~/image/a.png" it will give relative path and should work.

Comment: just for test add image control to your page and browse for ImageUrl property through property windows and look for ImageUrl lets see what kind of path VS generates.

Comment: property window shows name of image bt doesnot show image url .pls help me

Comment: pls see this url "http://devweb.tsgdomain.com/AmericaneyewdcNew/News.aspx?ModuleID=7"

Comment: ya image does not disply.pls open it in chrome.only alt text is shon "image" not image

Comment: @user602023 u expect to see an image on page right? where is this image supposed to be? i want to look fr source

Comment: yup.it is not display.see its page view source.it is shown image path bt on the page no image is dere.I also look property window .property window also doesnot show any  Image url.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong URL.

When you do :

```
        String testURL = Server.MapPath("~/ENewsImage/" + iNewsID + "_1" + Extension);
        Response.Redirect(testURL);
```

Is your image there?
Make sure the URL is correct by printing it to the screen or visiting it.

Comment: ya .i use it and it shows image bt it doesnot display any image on the page

Comment: pls see this url "http://devweb.tsgdomain.com/AmericaneyewdcNew/News.aspx?ModuleID=7"